# InfluxDB query using regular expression is not working

Tags: influxdb, influxql

I am using InfluxDB and have below mention data in measurement against field "jkey"

```
/interfaces/interface[name='xe-1/0/4']/state/counters/out-queue[queue-number='0']/allocated-buffer-size
/interfaces/interface[name='xe-1/0/5']/state/counters/out-queue[queue-number='0']/allocated-buffer-size
/interfaces/interface[name='xe-1/0/4']/state/counters/out-queue[queue-number='0']/allocated-buffer-size
```

I am using below mention query which is working fine with  above data.

```
select * from "measurement" where jkey =~ /interfaces\/interface.*/;
```

Now, i want to select only those records that have value 'xe-1/0/5' in it.

Below Query is also working fine as long as "[" is not part of query.

```
 select * from "measurement" where jkey =~ /name='xe-1\/0\/5']\/state\/counters\/in-pkts.*/ ;
```

Wondering what i am missing to escape in below mention query?

```
select * from "measurement" where jkey =~ /interfaces\/interface[name='xe-1\/0\/5']\/state\/counters\/in-pkts.*/;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Escaping this way fix the issue:

```
select * from "measurement" where jkey =~ /interfaces\/interface\[name='xe-1\/0\/5']\/state\/counters\/in-pkts.*/;
```